# How to embed images in blog post with React and Django

Tags: django, reactjs

i'm developing a blog for a friend using React and Django, Now I have to develop the text editor that he's going to use to write the articles but I don't know what to do in case of he wanting to embed images(not uploading them to the backend but using a external source like imgur,etc) on the text field between paragraphs, I suppose that django is not going to accept an `<img/>` being posted to the database on a text field, so my question is: do i need to handle this on the frontend or in the backend? sorry if it is a dumb question but i've been thinking how to approach this and i can't find a way.

models.py

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    text = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

EDIT:
This question has nothing to do with the ones that are supossedly duplicates, I'm sorry if I wasn't clear and now I'm going to try to explain it again: Imagine that you are developing a blog with a react frontend and a django backend, now you need to develop the frontend for creating articles and posting them to the backend, the following problem shows up: There's going to be a text input for the title of the article and then there's going to be another text input for the text of the article, what if the person that is writing the blog post wants to insert an image INSIDE that text field and then post it and save it to the database, an `<img>` tag is not possible since django is not going to save code directly to a text field in the database without cleaning it, so how I'm supposed to tackle this problem?? I hope I explained it well, thank you in advance!

Comment: I think it would be better for you to use one of the available editor options at https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/wysiwyg/ rather than rolling your own.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/48293543/5739514

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading Image in a React+Django app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239941/loading-image-in-a-reactdjango-app)